# restore default incoming email settings

Tags: 2010, event-handlers

I wrote an email event receiver for a list, which override the default incoming email settings (I now only have an option to turn it on/off and set the email, and the rest is expected to be handled by my custom code).

However, when I now remove the email event receiver from my farm, the incoming email settings are not restored to their default.

Is there a way to restore SharePoint's default email event receiver to a list?

Do I have to recreate the list from scratch now?

Comment: Does your FeatureDeactivated code detach your custom event receiver from the list?

Comment: Yes, my feature should be deactivating as normal. When the feature is not active and I send in an email, nothing happens.

In fact, if I save the list as a template and create a different one with an entirely different name, the settings are still truncated for incoming emails.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I have a similar problem, where activating a feature that attaches an email event receiver truncates the Incoming Email Settings for the list.